# How decide between <asp:label> or <h2></h2>

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone please help me regarding design of aspx page.

When we design aspx GUI then we have few option for heading/ controls label like webcontrols/ html controls.

Is there any performance benefit we gain while using html controls for static values rather using webcontols like heading of form, controls label.

I think for multilingual website we cannot use html controls for static text. Isn't?

Comment: You meant `<asp:label>` right?

Comment: Thanks, for editing wrong spellings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plain HTML tags have better performance than ASP controls. You can use static HTML for a multilingual web site but then you'd have to develop your own internationalization framework for it.

Comment: Actually i am getting multingual resources from resource file *.resx. 
I don't know how to bind resources with literal controls like <h2> for heading of form etc.

Answer (score 2):

If it's multilingual and you want to make use of the .NET i18n system (which you should) then yes, you should use server-side controls for the text. But you can obviously just use `literal` controls, and still control the formatting via `<h2>` and whatever else. Up to you.

Comment: Can you please tell, how to bind asp.net *.resx resource file with literal controls (<h2>)?

Comment: You can't, you bind them to an `<asp:Literal>` control. That's what I was referring to; apologies if it was confusing.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it explains how to use Localisation with html elements.